# After access to sql migration using SSMA only 100 rows are being returned

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-migration-assi

I migrated an access db to SQL using SSMA. My application still contacts the Access .mdb file and returns the record.
before migration : the table which is being used to populate data in the UI has 1000 rows and displays 1000 rows if the application uses the non migrated .mdb file.

post migration: the mdb file which is used by the application returns only 100 records..I tried by having exactly 100 records it worked. but then I tried with 101, which started throwing connectivity error.

How to handle this. Does SSMA have any restriction on the number of records to be returned after migration?

very urgent.Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that use SSIS in order to convert your data from access to SQL server.

If you don't want to use SSIS I suggested that copy date from your access database and paste in Excel file, and then convert your data from Excel to SQL server ( I think that column data type or column size cause that you can't convert from Access to SQL Server).

Comment: Mehdi, thanks for your reply.let me explain you precisely.I have no problem in the migration process. the table and data are getting migrated with out any issue. I have problem only while accessing the data from the database.Again the problem is only when the table has more than 100 rows.up till 100 rows no issues at all.